# when i run DropPlot.xcodeproj, the file has been successfully compiled. however, nothing shows up

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-plot

when i run DropPlot.xcodeproj, the file has been successfully compiled. 
however, nothing shows up. 
am i supposed to get a plot where the data is loaded from a csv file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DropPlot example includes a sample CSV file in the folder named "SampleCSVFiles". The app doesn't open any windows until you open a file. Run the app and open the CSV file using the File menu. You should then see a simple line plot.

Comment: ya i am able to see the simple line plot output now... your steps worked... i just want to know whether is it possible to get the output in DropPlot directly in the simulator rather than calling the CSV file externally..

Comment: is that possible to modify drop plot code so that the output graph can be  displayed in iphone simulator??